# Why am I unable to see Manage External user option in my contacts detail page?

Tags: community

I'm new to salesforce and communities,I've enabled communities in my org and created custom log in page and custom landing page. I want to test the login page. 
I am uanble to see Manage external user option in my contacts details page.
Can any tell me what I have to do to see that option and how to create users for my community ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your page layout allowed this button to appear. If not just drag it on your page layout. you will be fine.